# Issue when replacing WP database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I removed all tables from my WP database and imported .sql file from another exported database. When I access website it started installing WordPress and after installation none of my imported post are visible. What I have done wrong?

Comment: Your wp_config file is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to consider when moving databases from one site to another..

1. check wp_config file so it uses the correct information
2. once database in imported, ensure your `siteurl` and `home` option_name entries point to the correct address in `wp_options` table
3. permanalinks are updated
4. you have all plugin/theme files in place